# how to get data from database and save to session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
public  function getLoginInfo($username,$password){
        $conn=DB::connect();
        session_start();
        $sql="select * from owner where o_email='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' and o_password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 $_SESSION['email']=$username;
                 $_SESSION['password']=$password;
            }
            header("location:../owner/owner_dashboard.php");
        } else {
            header("location:../owner/owner_login.php");
        }
         $conn->close();
    }
```

i have added username and password to my session array but i also want to save id into session array which is stored into databse as "o_id"

Comment: mixing mysqli with mysql

Comment: so what i can do now can you correct this code? @Saty

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and better use bind and prepare statement'

Comment: ...or better yet: [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Do another query to get your data and save in session as you do for email and password

Comment: Btw... are you storing passwords in plain text in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicate the process than necessary. mysql_ extensions are also deprecated.Therefore, you should not use them. use prepare statements which prevent against sql injections. In additional, there is no need for you to store the password in the session. Your password should be stored in the database as hashed so storing it in session wont be reliable to you. Once you find a match against the username and password you searched for, you only need to store the username in the session. In your application, you can compare against the username of logged in area. I modified your code to a much cleaner solution. I had to made few assumptions such as your conn is a PDO.

```
public function getLoginInfo($username,$password)
{
    //start the session only if it has not started somewhere else
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        session_start();
    }

    //try to query the database
    try {
        $conn = DB::connect();
        $sql = 'Select * from owner where o_email= :email and o_password = :password';
        $conn->prepare($sql);
        $res = $conn->execute(array(':email' => $username, ':password' => $password));

        //check if the data exist. only true if result set is greater than 0
        if ($res->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$username;
            header("location:../owner/owner_dashboard.php");
            exit("login success, redirecting to dashboard...");
        }

        //doesnt exit so go back to login
        header("location:../owner/owner_login.php");
        exit('Invalid username or password. Redirecting back to lgoin...');
    }

    //Error is only output for debugging purpose. I would encourage turn this off in production
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, it must be clear that if you are querying for logging
>   in, then query will return only one row, so using while is
>   meaningless.

```
public  function getLoginInfo($username,$password){
        $conn=DB::connect();
        session_start();
        $sql="select * from owner where o_email='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' and o_password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// Edited from here

            // output data of each row
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $arraydata[$row['id']] = $row;
                 $_SESSION['user_info']=$arraydata;
                 $_SESSION['current_loggedin_id']=$row['id'];

            header("location:../owner/owner_dashboard.php");
        } else {
            header("location:../owner/owner_login.php");
        }
         $conn->close();
    }
```